# React Native - Passing Data Across Screens

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, stack-navigator

I'm having some trouble with a `react-native` app. I can't figure out how to pass data across screens.

I realize that there are other similar questions that are answered on SO, however the solutions did not work for me.

I'm using the `StackNavigator`. Here's my setup in my `App.js` file.

```
export default SimpleApp = StackNavigator({
    Home: { screen: HomeScreen },
    Categories: { screen: CategoriesScreen }, // send from here
    Category: { screen: CategoryScreen }      // to here
});
```

I have a `TouchableHighlight` component which has a `onPress` event that will navigate to the desired screen. This is on my `Categories.js` file/screen.

```
<TouchableHighlight onPress={(id) => {
    const { navigate } = this.props.navigation;
    navigate('Category', { category: id });
}}>
    <Text>{name}</Text>
</TouchableHighlight>
```

When I click the element, the screen does indeed switch to `category`, however it fails to send the `props` data.

So when I check the data in my `Category` screen, it returns undefined. I have tried the following methods:

```
this.props.category
this.props.navigation.state.category;
this.props.navigation.state.params.category
```

How exactly can I access that data that I passed in 
the `navigate` method?

```
navigate('Category', { category: id });
```

---

Edit: Here is my actual code structure:

The `data` comes from a `API`.

```
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    var name = data[i].name;
    var id = data[i].id;
    categoryComponents.push(
        <Card key={id}>
            <CardItem>
                <Body>
                    <TouchableHighlight onPress={(id) => {
                        const { navigate } = this.props.navigation;
                        navigate('Category', { params: { category: id } });
                    }}>
                        <Text>{name + " " + id}</Text>
                    </TouchableHighlight>
                </Body>
            </CardItem>
        </Card>
    );
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your problem isn't sending the parameter. You are sending it right and reading it right. Your error is related to that your `id` is undefined.

You should fix your code like below,

```
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    var name = data[i].name;
    var id = data[i].id;
    categoryComponents.push(
        <Card key={id}>
            <CardItem>
                <Body>
                    <TouchableHighlight onPress={(event) => {
                        // onPress event fires with an event object
                        const { navigate } = this.props.navigation;
                        navigate('Category', { category: id });
                    }}>
                        <Text>{name + " " + id}</Text>
                    </TouchableHighlight>
                </Body>
            </CardItem>
        </Card>
    );
}
```

And you can read your parameter like below.

```
this.props.navigation.state.params.category
```

Comment: Much thanks! I've been stuck on this fire awhile. Was I overriding the `id` variable because I made it a parameter?

Comment: Yes you were overriding parameters so the id you were trying to pass was not actually the id you created in your for loop.

Answer (score 0):

From parent screen:

```
navigate({ routeName: 'Category',  params: { category: id } })
```

or

```
navigate('Category', { category: id })
```

From child screen:

`const category = this.props.navigation.state.params.category`

Comment: I just tried this, however it still seems to be returning `undefined`.

Comment: Where does your id come from in <TouchableHighlight onPress={(id) => {...?

Comment: This is wrong I'm afraid. Parameter passing is wrong.

Comment: You were missing a parenthesis. I edited the answer.

Comment: The updated answer seems to be worse. The page does not navigate or send the data. Nothing happens.

Comment: Are you using Redux?

Answer (score 0):

So looking at the above described issue I think you are looking for something like `screenProps` (documented [here](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigators/stack#Screen-Navigation-Options)).

This allows you to pass a specific props across screens.

I hope this helps. Please let me know if you need anything else.

Answer (score 0):

Using the following code snippet, you can navigate to another screen with some values.

```
navigate({ Home: 'HomeScreen',  params: { username: 'abcd' } })
```

and you can collect the parameter at HomeScreen using,

```
this.props.navigation.state.params.username
```